# Preserve unicode in java

Tags: java, unicode

I am trying to print a string with the unicode characters "`\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217`"

How can I print the same? Java converts the above string into non-readable format, as if it is using its default character conversion for unicode. How can I avoid it from happening?

I am running it on OS X.

Edit1: Please provide a solution without adding backslash

Comment: Do you want to print `\u65e5...` or the corresponding unicode characters?

Comment: I just want the string mentioned above to print as it is. Java tends to convert it once assigned directly yo a string.

Comment: It doesn't "tend to". That's how you specify Unicode literals inside Java source code.

Comment: @AkD If you want to print just the string "as it is", what is the problem? Perhaps that it is *not* what you think it is.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "a string with the unicode characters."  As you can see, many of us are confused as to whether you mean a string whose first character is `(char) 0x65e5` or a string whose first six characters are `{ '\\', 'u', '6', '5', 'e', '5' }`.  You say "Java converts the above string into a non-readable format."  What is the non-readable format?  What are you seeing?

Comment: @VGR  See the double quotes around the string. Assign this in java string object as String vgr = "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217" .Now try to do system.out.print . Let me know if you get the same string if yes , let me know your encoding font. Anyways I have tried with utf-8, 16 and cp420 encoding for far without success. I get something like "??? @" etc

Comment: By "have tried with utf-8, 16, and cp420" are you referring to something in your code?  You should not need to specify an encoding anywhere.  When I do `System.out.println("\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217");` I see six CJK characters (on Linux, where my system locale is en_US.utf8).  What do you see if you execute `javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\u65e5\u672c\u8a9e\u6587\u5b57\u5217");`?

Comment: @VGR Yes I am talking about doing it through code . My eclipse is pointing to a different font on Os X. Let me try changing that to UTF-8.

Comment: Please show us the line(s) of code where you specify an encoding.

Comment: Protobuff serializer was encoding by itself in upstream project. Thats the reason I had hard time figuring the issue. Many ppl face this issue. I dont understand why its was voted down , it took me sometime to figure this out since this chars did not make any sense. It was a genuine question.
But thanks everyone for helping out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to print exactly that then you need to escape your backslashes:

```
\\u65e5\\u672c\\u8a9e\\u6587\\u5b57\\u5217
```

Edit: If this is not ok, or even if it is, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2406827/781965) - [`escapeJava`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String) from Apache commons sounds like it might be what you're looking for. Or maybe one of the `escapeHtml` methods? I'm not entirely sure if `escapeJava` will work for unicode.

Comment: this answer is wrong. There are no backslashes.  The OP has a unicode string and wants to print the encoded version of it.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky Does he? That's not how I read the question, and he hasn't responded to Ingo's comment yet - If he says it's not what he wants I'll happily delete the answer.

Comment: @Jeff well you have modified the string.Say I have millions of records with such format. Its not feasible to append backslash in front of all the characters. Do we have a way to let java to stop converting unicodes

Comment: @AkD See my edit - hopefully that will help? Edit: Of course, it's not ideal - it'll add overhead to printing them - but AFAIK there's no built in way of doing what you're asking.

Comment: @AkD - if you have records with this format, than printing them is not a problem. The \uXXXX are only replaced in source code.

Answer (score 0):

escape your backslashes

```
String s = "\\u65e5\\u672c\\u8a9e\\u6587\\u5b57\\u5217";
```

Answer (score 0):

One could do the following for each character `ch` in the string:

```
  int c = ch;
  printf("\\u%04x", c);
```