# String output with quotes

Tags: java

I get in put string as below

{key: IsReprint, value:COPY};{key: IsCancelled, value:CANCELLED}

I want to convert above string as below in my output...,want to add quotes to the string (key , value pairs).

```
{"key": "IsReprint", "value":"COPY"};{"key": "IsCancelled", "value":"CANCELLED"}
```

Please assist..thanks in advance..

```
    String input="{key: IsReprint, value:COPY};{key: IsCancelled,value:CANCELLED}";
    if(input.contains("key:") && input.contains("value:") ){
        input=input.replaceAll("key", "\"key\"");       
        input=input.replaceAll("value", "\"value\"");       
        input=input.replaceAll(":", ":\""); 
        input=input.replaceAll("}", "\"}"); 
        input=input.replaceAll(",", "\","); 
        //System.out.println("OUTPUT----> "+input);
    }
```

I above code has problem if input string as below

{key: BDTV, value:Africa Ltd | Reg No: 433323240833-C23441,GffBLAB | VAT No: 4746660239035
Level 6}

Comment: you will have to insert `\"` before/after every word

Comment: What kind of a problem do you have? Can you give the expected output?

Comment: @Yuri ,I am expecting the output as below....{"key": "IsReprint", "value":"COPY"};{"key": "IsCancelled", "value":"CANCELLED"}

Comment: @Murali Please Check my Answer update. +1 to question !

Comment: Thanks @RDR..Appreciated

Comment: @Murali You can always accept one answer that seems good enough to you. Or you can raise further concerns if any. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex to accomplish the same, but more concisely:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JsonScanner {

    private final static String JSON_REGEX = "\\{key: (.*?), value:(.*?)(\\};|\\}$)";

    /**
     * Splits the JSON string into key/value tokens.
     * 
     * @param json  the JSON string to format
     * @return  the formatted JSON string
     */
    private String findMatched(String json) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(JSON_REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(json);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        while (m.find()) {
            result.append("\"key\"=\"" + m.group(1) + "\", ");
            result.append("\"value\"=\"" + m.group(2) + "\" ; ");
            System.out.println("m.group(1)=" + m.group(1) + " ");
            System.out.println("m.group(2)=" + m.group(2) + " ");
            System.out.println("m.group(3)=" + m.group(3) + "\n");
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        JsonScanner jsonScanner = new JsonScanner();
        String result = jsonScanner.findMatched("{key: TVREG, value:WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br/>Plot No.56634773,Road};{key: REGISTRATION, value:SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road}");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

You might have to tweak the regex or output string to meet your exact requirements, but this should give you an idea of how to get started...

Comment: Thanks 6006604,but I used below .It didnt give exact result.Can you try below input string ..    String result = jsonScanner.findMatched("{key: TVREG, value:WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br/>Plot No.56634773,Road};{key: REGISTRATION, value:SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road}");

Comment: I tweaked the regex and added some debugging logs to show what the regex is capturing.  there might be a more elegant way to write the regex, but this seems to work...

Comment: Wow...This worked.Thanks a lot.Let me test for different scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

[You have to escape characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)

[How do I escape a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406121/how-do-i-escape-a-string-in-java)

For example:
    String s = "{\"key\": \"IsReprint\""; // will be print as {"key": "IsReprint"

Comment: @Bala Murali Can you close the question? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I think you should cast all elements of the string to the unified standard. Otherwise, you'll have to deal with different cases and create code for their replacement. i.e. In case ":" and ": "  you have to foresee both situations in your code.

Comment: Well, I can't come up with a simple and grateful solution, so I can only advice such a solution: input=input.replaceAll(": ", ":").replaceAll(":", ": \"");

Answer (score 0):

The double quote character has to be escaped with a backslash in a Java string literal. Other characters that need special treatment include:

Carriage return and newline: "\r" and "\n"
Backslash: "\"
Single quote: "\'"
Horizontal tab and form feed: "\t" and "\f".

Comment: Thanks Martin  and Yuri.I updated my question..Please check again.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the exact result as you want!

```
public static void main(String s[]){
     String test = "{key: TVREG, value:WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road};{key: REGISTRATION, value:SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road}";
         StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
                   String[] keyValOld = test.split(";");

                   for(int j=0; j<keyValOld.length; j++){
                       String keyVal = keyValOld[j].substring(1,keyValOld[j].length()-1);

                       String[] parts = keyVal.split("(:)|(,)",4);
                       sb.append("{");
                       for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) { 
                           sb.append("\""+parts[i].trim()+"\": \""+parts[i + 1].trim()+"\"");
                           if(i+2<parts.length) sb.append(", ");
                   }
                       sb.append("};");
                   }
                   System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: It will remove _all the spaces_ in the string. I guess it won't be a desirable result.

Comment: Moreover, it adds additional symbols: "{"  "}"

Comment: Thanks ..but if my string as below then it is problem ..{key: TVREG, value:WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road};{key: REGISTRATION, value:SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road}

Comment: Thanks Yuri... you are right...if data has addintional {,} ,: values in Value then its problem

Comment: my bad guys.. forgot to add elseif instead of if.. silly copy paste :) now it is not addng additional chars

Comment: @RDR,if my input string is as   ".{key: TVREG, value:WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road};{key: REGISTRATION, value:SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road} " ..THEN I AM GETTING PROBLEM...CAN YOU PLS TRY THIS INPUT STRING

Comment: {"key": "TVREG", "value": "WestAfricaLtd|VATNo": "1009034324829/{"834324"}<br/>PlotNo.56634773", "Road"};{"key": "REGISTRATION", "value": "SouthAfricaLtd|VATNo": "1009034324829/{"834324"}<br/>PlotNo.56634773", "Road"}

I am getting this.. tell me what should be the O/P

Comment: I WANT FINAL OUT PUT STRING AS BELOW  :::: ".{"key": "TVREG", "value":"WestAfrica Ltd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road"};{"key": "REGISTRATION", "value":"SouthAfricaLtd | VAT No: 1009034324829/{834324}<br />Plot No. 56634773, Road"}

Comment: @RDR ,,If see my input string its having KEY VALUE PAIRS...i want the key and values should be in the double quotes..That is my requirement.

Comment: updated the answer. It is still half of the solution. I will update once I get time

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using a regexp to split your input into key / value pairs and then aggregating the result using the format you wish :

```
// Split key value pairs
final String regexp = "\\{(.*?)\\}";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
final List<String[]> keyValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find())
{
    final String[] keyValue = input.substring(m.start() + 1, m.end() - 1) // "key: IsReprint, value:COPY"
        .substring(5) // "IsReprint, value:COPY"
        .split(", value:"); // ["IsReprint", "COPY"]
    keyValuePairs.add(keyValue);
}

// Aggregate
final List<String> newKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.stream().map(keyValue ->
{
    return "{\"key\": \"" + keyValue[0] + "\", \"value\":\"" + keyValue[1] + "\"}";
}).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(StringUtils.join(newKeyValuePairs.toArray(), ";"));
```

The result for the folowing input string

```
final String input = "{key: IsReprint, value:COPY};{key: IsCancelled, value:CANCELLED};{key: BDTV, value:Africa Ltd | Reg No: 433323240833-C23441,GffBLAB | VAT No: 4746660239035<br />Level 6}";
```

is `{"key": "IsReprint", "value":"COPY"};{"key": "IsCancelled", "value":"CANCELLED"};{"key": "BDTV", "value":"Africa Ltd | Reg No: 433323240833-C23441,GffBLAB | VAT No: 4746660239035<br />Level 6"}`

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, but I am getting compilation errors at // Aggregate block.. // Aggregate
final List<String> newKeyValuePairs = keyValuePairs.stream().map(keyValue ->
{
    return "{\"key\": \"" + keyValue[0] + "\", \"value\":\"" + keyValue[1] + "\"}";
}).collect(Collectors.toList());Can you kindly check this statement

Comment: Well, difficult to say without knowing what is the error. Could you give us the error message ?
The code compiles just fine on my computer.
What version of Java do you use ? You are pointing at a line that uses Java 8 tools (Stream).

Comment: If you are not using Java 8, you can just iterate with a for loop to replace the Stream :
   final List<String> newKeyValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
   for (final String[] keyValue : keyValuePairs)
   {
    newKeyValuePairs.add("{\"key\": \"" + keyValue[0] + "\", \"value\":\"" + keyValue[1] + "\"}");
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="{key: IsReprint, value:COPY};{key: IsCancelled, value:CANCELLED};{key: BDTV,value:Africa Ltd | Reg No: 433323240833-C23441,GffBLAB | VAT No: 4746660239035 Level 6}";
        Matcher m1 = Pattern.compile("key:" + "(.*?)" + ",\\s*value:").matcher(input);
        Matcher m2 = Pattern.compile("value:" + "(.*?)" + "}").matcher(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(m1.find() && m2.find()){
              sb.append("{\"key\": ")
                .append("\"")
                .append(m1.group(1).trim())
                .append("\", \"value\":")
                .append("\"")
                .append(m2.group(1).trim())
                .append("\"};");
        }
        String output = sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1).toString();
        System.out.println(output);
    }    
}
```