# How to get Custom Url

Tags: android, url

In my java file URL is static like

```
String URL = "https://aa.com/hospital/dmc.jpg";
```

But I want the URL will come from database like

```
https://aa.com/hospital/dmc.jpg
```

and after adding " sign at the first and the last word and put into a string.
How can I get that?

Comment: Please be more specific, what is your problem?

Comment: i want like that (but it's wrong) String a= value; String url = "\'"+a+"\n"";

Comment: Okay, let's try to understand what is your problem...
Do you want to delete  _ "_  from your string?

Comment: add " sign manually in string url at start and end position.

Comment: İ ll post answer now please wait

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by  **replace()** function

---

```
    url = url.replace("https:","\"https:").replace(".jpg",".jpg\"");
```

---

You can get more information here

[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406121/how-do-i-escape-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Or if you want to work with more complex string that the end of it will change in order to add " you should use stringBuilder...