# How do i continuously escape \t in java?

Tags: java, escaping, tap

I searched for same questions.([How do I escape a string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406121/how-do-i-escape-a-string-in-java)) but i can't solve my problem.

***part of source code***
System.out.println("year : "+year+"\t"+"rate_year : "+rate_year+"\t"+"rate_month : "+rate_month);

but when i print that
.
.
.
year : 10       rate_year : 0.4 rate_month : 0.03333333333333333

This prints first "\t"
why all "\t"s are not adapted???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "\t" advances to the next tab stop. If one changes the text description slightly, notice the alignment:

```
System.out.println("year : "+year+"\t"+"rate_year : "+rate_year+"\t"+"rate_month : "+rate_month);
System.out.println("year : "+year+"\t"+"ry : "+rate_year+"\t"+"rm : "+rate_month);
```

Output:

```
year : 10   rate_year : 0.4 rate_month : 0.333333    
year : 10   ry : 0.4        rm : 0.333333
```

I believe the issue is simply where the tab column is falling.

On a different note, if the goal is column alignment, it might be better to use `printf` and specific column sizes. See, e.g., [this answer on formatting with \t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536806/1277259)

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        System.out.printf("year : %3d rate_year : %6f rate_month : %-6f\n", 
                i,
                rate_year,
                rate_month);
}
```

Output:

```
year :   8 rate_year : 0.400000 rate_month : 0.333333  
year :   9 rate_year : 0.400000 rate_month : 0.333333      
year :  10 rate_year : 0.400000 rate_month : 0.333333  
year :  11 rate_year : 0.400000 rate_month : 0.333333
```